# Python split a list into various list by month

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a list of objects (django model) that contain date attribute among others. day/month/year and I need to split it into groups by month and year, so if I have:

```
list_dates = ['1-10-2018','4-10-2018','1-11-2018',
            '6-10-2018', '3-10-2018', '6-11-2018', '9-11-2018']
```

which is actually:

```
list_objects = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g...z]
```

edit: and each object(model) has a `date = models.Datetime()` and i need to pick and group objects that have the same month and year.

turn it into

```
splitted_list = {[a,b,e],[c,d,e]}# same month, same year grouped together

list_grouped = {['1-10-2018','4-10-2018','1-10-2018','6-10-2018'],

['3-11-2018', '6-11-2018', '9-11-2018']}
```

and I have not been able to find an easy or doable way to do this
Hope someone has some idea of how to do this. Have been trying it for days now.

```
'class my_model<(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="model_prods")
    ...  
    ...

class list_v2(models.Model):
    list_owner= models.ForeignKey(my_model, related_name='date_list', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @Selcuk
my problem is that I have a list of objects, `product.demands.all().order_by('date'):` or `p = Product.objects.filter(owner=request.user)`
and the object has a date = models.Datetime()
so i dont think itertools.groupby would be of use. either that or i dont understand how it works, hope its the latter, but for what i have seen it works on tuples of list(if I have the semantics right)

Comment: Granted you'll have to massage your data structure a bit first. Try `[(int(i) for i in x.split('-')) for x in list_dates]` for example.

Comment: **@Selcuk**, You can't use statement like `{[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]}` in Python but `{[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]}` is ok. So use/create `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]` type list as a final result or you may use dictionay like `{'2018': {'10':['12-10-2018', '12-10-2018'], '11': ['12-11-2018', '9-11-2018']}}` to organize your dates based on year & month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Zealot91**, you can try the below code examples.

> **Note:** You can't use statement like `{[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]}` in Python but `{(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)}` is ok.
>
> So I will suggest you to use/create `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]` type list as a final result or you may use dictionay like `{'2018': {'10':['12-10-2018', '12-10-2018'], '11': ['12-11-2018', '9-11-2018']}}` to organize your dates based on year & month.

```
>>> s = {[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
>>> s = {(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)}
>>> s
set([(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)])
>>>
```

## » Example 1

```
import json

# List of dates
list_dates = [
                '1-10-2018','4-10-2018','1-11-2018',
                '6-10-2018', '3-10-2018', '6-11-2018', 
                '9-11-2018'
            ]

d = {}

for date in list_dates:
    day, month, year = date.split('-')

    if year in d:
        if month in d[year]:
            d[year][month].append(date)
        else:
            d[year][month] = [date]
    else:
        d[year] = {month: [date]}

# Pretty printing d (Example 1.1: dictionary)
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
"""
    {
        "2018": {
            "11": [
                "1-11-2018",
                "6-11-2018",
                "9-11-2018"
            ],
            "10": [
                "1-10-2018",
                "4-10-2018",
                "6-10-2018",
                "3-10-2018"
            ]
        }
    }
"""

# Creating and pretty printing list_grouped (Example 1.2: list of lists)
list_grouped = [months_list for year in d.values() for months_list in year.values()]
print(json.dumps(list_grouped, indent=4))
"""
    [
        [
            "1-11-2018",
            "6-11-2018",
            "9-11-2018"
        ],
        [
            "1-10-2018",
            "4-10-2018",
            "6-10-2018",
            "3-10-2018"
        ]
    ]
"""
```

## » Example 2

```
# List of dates
import json

list_dates = [
                '1-10-2018','28-01-2017', '4-10-2018','1-11-2018',
                '6-10-2018', '3-10-2018', '6-12-2016', '6-11-2018', 
                '9-11-2018', '15-11-2016', '14-05-1992', '03-11-2017',
                '1-10-2018','25-01-2017', '4-11-2017','1-11-2016',
                '6-10-2018', '3-11-2016', '6-12-2017', '6-10-2013', 
                '9-12-2014', '15-10-2013', '20-05-1992', '03-12-2017',
                '19-12-2014', '15-10-2013', '20-05-1992', '03-12-2017'
            ]

d = {}

for date in list_dates:
    day, month, year = date.split('-')

    if year in d:
        if month in d[year]:
            d[year][month].append(date)
        else:
            d[year][month] = [date]
    else:
        d[year] = {month: [date]}

# Pretty printing d (Example 2.1: dictionary)
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

"""
    {
        "1992": {
            "05": [
                "14-05-1992",
                "20-05-1992",
                "20-05-1992"
            ]
        },
        "2018": {
            "11": [
                "1-11-2018",
                "6-11-2018",
                "9-11-2018"
            ],
            "10": [
                "1-10-2018",
                "4-10-2018",
                "6-10-2018",
                "3-10-2018",
                "1-10-2018",
                "6-10-2018"
            ]
        },
        "2014": {
            "12": [
                "9-12-2014",
                "19-12-2014"
            ]
        },
        "2017": {
            "11": [
                "03-11-2017",
                "4-11-2017"
            ],
            "12": [
                "6-12-2017",
                "03-12-2017",
                "03-12-2017"
            ],
            "01": [
                "28-01-2017",
                "25-01-2017"
            ]
        },
        "2016": {
            "11": [
                "15-11-2016",
                "1-11-2016",
                "3-11-2016"
            ],
            "12": [
                "6-12-2016"
            ]
        },
        "2013": {
            "10": [
                "6-10-2013",
                "15-10-2013",
                "15-10-2013"
            ]
        }
    }
"""

# Creating and pretty printing list_grouped (Example 2.2: list of lists)
list_grouped = [months_list for year in d.values() for months_list in year.values()]
print(json.dumps(list_grouped, indent=4))

"""
    [
        [
            "14-05-1992",
            "20-05-1992",
            "20-05-1992"
        ],
        [
            "1-11-2018",
            "6-11-2018",
            "9-11-2018"
        ],
        [
            "1-10-2018",
            "4-10-2018",
            "6-10-2018",
            "3-10-2018",
            "1-10-2018",
            "6-10-2018"
        ],
        [
            "9-12-2014",
            "19-12-2014"
        ],
        [
            "03-11-2017",
            "4-11-2017"
        ],
        [
            "6-12-2017",
            "03-12-2017",
            "03-12-2017"
        ],
        [
            "28-01-2017",
            "25-01-2017"
        ],
        [
            "15-11-2016",
            "1-11-2016",
            "3-11-2016"
        ],
        [
            "6-12-2016"
        ],
        [
            "6-10-2013",
            "15-10-2013",
            "15-10-2013"
        ]
    ]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually group by month and year by annotating the queryset directly like so:

```
filtered_queryset = queryset.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'), year=TruncYear('date'))
filtered_queryset.values_list('month', 'year')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#datefield-truncation

Comment: Is that the raw sql queries?

Comment: No, it's a queryset function built into Django

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` object to keep track of combination of month and year as keys and their corresponding position in the result list as values of those keys.

**Example**:

```
list_objects = [a, b, c...]
month_year_dict = {}
result = []

for obj in list_objects:
    dt = obj.date_field_name
    day, month, year = dt.day, dt.month, dt.year

    key = month + "-" + year
    if month_year_dict.get(key, None):
        result[month_year_dict[key]].append(obj)
    else:
        result.append([obj])
        month_year_dict[key] = len(result) - 1

print(result)
```